# Android Bitmap/Drawable masking

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, mask

I need to textured some bitmap in ImageView. I use code bellow:

```
        Bitmap original - texture;                        
        Bitmap mask - image that I must textured;            
        Bitmap result -  result image;

        Canvas mCanvas = new Canvas(result);
        Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);            
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
        mCanvas.drawBitmap(original, 0, 0, null);
        mCanvas.drawBitmap(mask, 0, 0, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(null);            
        imgView.setImageBitmap(result);
        imgView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);
```

it's work but I have

mask
[image] 
 and
texture [image]
result image 
[image]

But I need black borders and circuit of the image. Anybody know solution how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution my problem was very simple. Instead

```
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
```

Need to use

```
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY));
```

And everything work like charm.